# Ionic item display in 2 lines multiple items

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have this html :

```
<ion-item text-wrap>
    <p class="fw-bold">Rules & Guidelines </p> <br />
    <ion-text>
        <ion-icon name="american-football" item-start></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>
            Voucher terms & conditions
        </ion-label>
        <ion-toggle color="secondary" item-end></ion-toggle>
    </ion-text>
</ion-item>
```

Now I want to display like this :

First line : `Rules & Guidelines`

Second line : `icon      Voucher terms & conditions     toogle`

Now I have all this content in one line, like this
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<ion-item><b>Rules & Guidelines</b></ion-item>
<ion-item>
  <ion-icon name="american-football" slot="start"></ion-icon>
  <ion-label>
    Voucher terms & conditions
  </ion-label>
  <ion-toggle color="secondary" slot="end"></ion-toggle>
</ion-item>
```

You should get this,

[image: Result]